# Building a Python cron job/web API for QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have some tasks that I'd like QGIS to do every day, or when triggered by an API call.

I'm trying to understand the architecture.

I can run QGIS on a VM, then have a Python script accessing it and an external database to process any imagery that has come in since the last time the script ran, right?

Alternately, is there a straightforward way for me to set up a Python web server and then take data from POST calls and run it through QGIS?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194055/script-that-runs-automatically-from-the-qgis-python-console-when-qgis-starts-us ?