# Running PyQGIS script inside QGIS console via Plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, qgis-python-console

I have some calculation and processing done on vector data. I have written code in pyqgis( and executing inside Console).I need to create a plugin (for my use only) which don't have any input button for loading vector and stuffs. It just have a button of "Process".

Is it possible for my plugin to access QGIS, open python console and run my script?

Don't write any "heavy" stuff I am new to QGIS Plugin and doing it for the first time.

Comment: Do you try the [cookbook PyQgis](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/)? Try this too [Qgis Simple Plugin](https://gis-ops.com/qgis-simple-plugin/)

Comment: for show console https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/132714/49538