# Showing editor by default in QGIS Python Console

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I use *startup.py* file in folder `%AppData%\QGIS\QGIS3` to open the Python Console at QGIS start.

Is there a way to also show the editor?

I browsed a lot of pages in the API, but didn't find the answer.

The code I use in *startup.py* is as follows:

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QDockWidget
from qgis.utils import iface #change made to original code

pythonConsole = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'PythonConsole')

if not pythonConsole or not pythonConsole.isVisible():
    iface.actionShowPythonDialog().trigger()
```

Credits to original code: [Showing Python Console when QGIS starts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132695/how-to-show-python-console-at-qgis-program-start)

Using @Mayo's answer, I adapted the *startup.py* script, which now reads like follows:

```py
import console
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QDockWidget

pythonConsole = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'PythonConsole')

if not pythonConsole or not pythonConsole.isVisible():
    iface.actionShowPythonDialog().trigger()
    pythonConsole = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'PythonConsole')
    python_console = pythonConsole.findChild(console.console.PythonConsoleWidget)

    for w in python_console.children():
        try:
            if w.text() == 'Show Editor':
                w.trigger()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Show the console by calling the `trigger()` function of the **Show Editor** button:

```py
import console
    
python_widget = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'PythonConsole')
python_console = python_widget.findChild(console.console.PythonConsoleWidget)
    
for w in python_console.children():
    try:
        if w.text() == 'Show Editor':
            w.trigger()
            break
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```