# Exporting messages in Python Console with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, export, qgis-python-console

I want to export the messages that appear on the Console Python (for example this below) using a script:

[image]

But I can't find a way to store it in a txt file. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really horrible way of finding the right widget, I can almost guarantee there is a more elegant way (suggestions welcome), but nonetheless:

```py
cons = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'PythonConsole')

children = cons.children()

pc = children[-1]               # console.console.PythonConsole
                
pcw = pc.children()[0]          # console.console.PythonConsoleWidget

shell = pcw.shellOutWidget 

scin = shell.children()[1]      # console.console_output.ShellOutputScintilla

contents = scin.text()          # console text

# write log to file
with open('console_log.txt', 'w+') as logfile:
    logfile.write(contents)
```

Comment: Nice code, however, I am getting the following error: `"AttributeError: 'QSplitter' object has no attribute 'shellOutWidget'"`

Comment: The weirdest child is this one `console.console.PythonConsoleWidge` ^_^

Comment: In that case, it's probably better to find the child using `if isinstance()` rather than by indexing. I thought that might causes issues...

Comment: And indeed. It took quite some digging to find my way through the hierarchy :)

Comment: At least we know where to look for: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132695/showing-python-console-when-qgis-starts @_@